# Where's the best place to create local variables that will be used in a display (using MVC principles)?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I was thinking of creating them in the controller and just pass the variable to the JSP but unsure if this is the way to go.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers pass data to Views via Models - see the [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the layer of segregation that has been made by **MVC** architecture itself says that you should do the processing from backend data **[after you get it from Model Bean]** in the **Controller**.

> In your question you have clearly mentioned that you want to know the
>   right place where to declare variables ? -> So you would want to do some processing on them e.g. change values based on some data or calculations right!!

**So make the variables in controller, obviously private data has to be taken care so do that in controller or the class file itself.**